# Change CSS Based on Mobile Orientation

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, mobile

What is the best approach to change a css file when a mobile application page orientation changes from landscape to portrait and vice versa.  I need to suport both Android and iPhone only. It seems media queries aren't the cleanest way, any other ideas?

Comment: Isn't there any option to bind to window resize event, and if X is bigger then Y it is landscape? And Y bigger then X you got portrait? Keep 1 var as a boolean, isLandscape and if it's changed, edit your stylesheet?

Comment: Why you think that CSS media queries aren't clean solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below JQuery code seems to work best for me...the binding examples did not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
               $(window).resize(function() {
                  alert(window.orientation);
                  });
               });
```

Answer (score 7):

Example

```
/* For portrait */
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  #toolbar {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* For landscape */

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  #toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 2.65em;
    height: 100%;
  }

  p {
    margin-left: 2em;
  }
}
```

For more details see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Managing_screen_orientation)

Answer (score 1):

First give your style sheet include line an id="cssElement" or something.

Then Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

   // The event for orientation change
   var onChanged = function() {

      // The orientation
      var orientation = window.orientation;

      if(orientation == 90) { 
          $('#cssElement').attr('href', '/path/to/landscape.css');
      } else {
          $('#cssElement').attr('href', '/path/to/portrait.css');
      }

   };

   // Bind the orientation change event and bind onLoad
   $(window).bind(orientationEvent, onChanged).bind('load', onChanged);

});
```

Comment: I thought `window.orientation` was a number, not a string.

Comment: ^^icktoofay You are right (fixed). I read something incorrectly. Anyway, this /should/ work when on a phone browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.onorientationchange event.